# can you tell me How to quit VIM quickfix? please

Tags: vim

I know that when you run :make in vim, you can use commands to go through each error like :cn and :cp. However, I often find myself scrolling through warnings that I don't need to fix. Is there a way to quit scrolling through the errors/warnings and resume editing? (I have heard that you can set Vim to ignore warnings, but I've been told it's difficult so I'm looking for something easier).

Comment: How about `gi`? This returns to the last edit location and continues editing there.

Answer (score 3):

you can close a quickfix window by using ccl[ose] :

```
:cclose
```

for ease of use i have mapped it to a key like so, such that pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> will automatically close it for me :

`nmap <F12> :silent! cclose<CR>`

**silent** tells vim to show no message when this key sequence is used